# Why does scalac box Int?

Tags: scala, int

I wrote the following very simple test:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.HashSet

class Test {
  def m() = {
    var s = new HashSet[Int]
    s = s + 1
  }
}
```

And figured out that it compiles to this code:

```
public class Test {
  public void m();
    Code:
       0: new           #12                 // class scala/collection/immutable/HashSet
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #15                 // Method scala/collection/immutable/HashSet."<init>":()V
       7: astore_1
       8: aload_1
       9: iconst_1
      10: invokestatic  #21                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
      13: invokevirtual #25                 // Method scala/collection/immutable/HashSet.$plus:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/immutable/HashSet;
      16: astore_1
      17: return

  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #30                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
}
```

As you can see, `1` is boxed before creating a new immutable set with 1 element. Why is it boxed. `Int extends AnyVal`, not `AnyRef`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exactly, `Int extends AnyVal`, not `AnyRef`. But the immutable [`HashSet[A]`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/HashSet.html) has `A` as parameter, which is not [specialized for primitive types](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/specialized.html), that is, it is not `@specialized(Int) A` or anything like that, so it can deal only with reference types that extend `AnyRef`, the primitive types must be boxed. This, fortunately, is hidden by the Scala compiler.

Comment: Reasonably to ask... Why isn't it specialized? Is there some obvious restriction?

Comment: @St.Antario I think mostly because it would blow up the size of the compiled standard library by factor 10x (because there are 9 primitive types, which are not reference types). In the case of `Map[X, Y]`, it would be factor 100x. However, there is no fundamental restriction, e.g. as far as I remember, [paulp's non-standard standard library](https://github.com/paulp/psp-std) could pervasively specialize on everything, and it worked (and it worked faster than the non-specialized versions).